# The model is unable to predict the proper action

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I added the story,

- story: interactive_story_1
  steps:

  - intent: call
    entities:

    - person: son
  - slot_was_set:

    - person: son
  - action: action_call
    and when i am running this on rasa interactive, it identifies the intent correctly, sets the slot properly but it predicts action_default_fallback with 0.3 probability and asks to run that instead of action_call which is clearly mentioned in the story!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it, there was a problem with my rasa core configuration, it was not trained properly so all the action predictions by the dialogue management model was faulty.